Yii2 Cache-control
i've read the documentation about YII2 Caching
So i set on my controller
public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            'verbs' => [
              'class' => VerbFilter::class,
              'actions' => [
                'logout' => ['post'],
              ],
            ],
            ['class' => 'yii\filters\HttpCache',
                'only' => ['index'],
                'cacheControlHeader' => 'public, max-age=3600'
            ],
        ];
    }

When i run a webpagetest for my site i get:

17 static files have inadequate cache settings.

and get this:

FAILED (No max-age or expires):

What i'm doing wrong?
This is what i see in the 

Is nginx configured to control cache on images? Which static files are not caching properly? If all assets then you should cache at the nginx level.
